# Get a decimal from a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a shopping cart, upon clicking `Add to cart` the user is redirected to a page that accepts the `id` of the product as a `GET` parameter, and based on that I want to retrieve its price, which I do like so with EF:

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(db.Products.Where(x => x.Id == productId).Select(x => x.Price));
```

However, when I click `Add to cart` and hit the url it redirects to, I get this error in VS:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Decimal]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

I am new to `.NET` so I might not be retrieving the price the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);

decimal? price = result?.Price;
```

Take the product with the specific `ID` and after that take his price if existing. This syntax is valid if you are using `C# 6.0`, if you are with previous C# version use: `if(result !=null) price = result.Price`